# How to generate random id's

Tags: php, mysql

I Was wondering how can i generate a random number for the id of the photo being any number and generate random id for the users id being any number for example:

num = photo id
idr = user id

```
yourphoto.php?num=60&idr=3
```

now what i want to do is generate something that doesn't tell the user what id number the photo is or user id is so something random.

Like That:

```
yourphoto.php?num=654654654648&idr=34546545621
```

Comment: You can use [uniqid](http://us1.php.net/uniqid). Make sure that you're not storing it in the database as an integer though!

Comment: so once i fetch the data from mysql i run uniqid()??

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about an id to display? Can you please update your post with your database table schema?

Comment: yeah how would i use uniqid to display the url or in other words how would i generate the photo id to diplay like a uniqid in the url

Comment: You could hash the value.

Comment: from the varialbe?
$var = 15465;
uniqid($var);
like that

Answer (score 3):

Check [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), it will meet your needs.

Kinda pseudo code ( related to the comments )

```
   //Insert into DB
    $new_photo = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'newphoto', 'unique' => uniqid()),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'newphoto2', 'unique' => uniqid())
    );

   // select everything from db
   $photos = $new_photo;

    //display photos
    foreach($photos as $photo){
            // display Link with $photo['unique'], <a href="link.php?num=$photo['unique']"
           var_dump($photo);    
    }


//GET Num
// select where unique = $_GET['num']
```

Since i guess you don't really understand, i'm going to be a nice guy and show you how it works. Make sure to remember this is just an example not good for production.

Create 2 PHP files, test.php and test2.php

## test.php

Run this once and it will create a new table called photos_temp and it will insert 2 photos.

```
// DB information
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";


// Create our photos_temp table
$test_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos_temp` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `unique` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

//Connect to DB
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Create Table
$table = $conn->prepare($test_query);
$table->execute();

// Data to insert into the database ( you can insert trough a form )
 $new_photos = array(
        array('name' => 'newphoto', 'unique' => uniqid()),
        array('name' => 'newphoto2', 'unique' => uniqid())
    );

 // Insert Query template
 $addquery = "INSERT INTO `photos_temp` (`name`, `unique`) VALUES (?, ?)";

 // foreach our data ( we will insert the 2 photos )
 foreach($new_photos as $photo){
            if($query = $conn->prepare($addquery)){
                    $query->bind_param('ss', $photo['name'], $photo['unique']);
                    $query->execute();
            }

 }

 echo 'finish inserting';
```

## test2.php

This will display the photos and link to your unique photo.

```
// DB information
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";


$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('Select * from photos_temp');
$stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<a href="?num='.$data['unique'].'">'.$data['name'].'</a><br/>';
}

if(isset($_GET['num'])){
    $num = $_GET['num'];

    $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM `photos_temp` WHERE `unique` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $photo = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($photo);
}
```

Comment: ohkay now say i fetch the user id and photo id from the mysql database and so what do i do run it inside the uniqid()??

Comment: You don't need to run anything, uniqid it will return a Unique STRING.
check this example http://codepad.viper-7.com/deHQkz

Comment: Create a new column on ur table "link", then update your data with link = uniqid

Comment: Update your table with the uniqid, then when you fetch your data you use it, yourphoto.php?num=$row['uniqid']; For more any other questions about how to insert/update/select the database, you should create another question or study a little bit mysql.

Comment: So, when you create the photo insert into the DB with the uniqid() string in a column, then you fetch all the photos and display the url with the column.

Comment: Now you have the logic down, so it should be pretty easy to migrate this to your code. hope it helps